# How can i send the correct answer and the chosen answer in another activity?

Tags: java, android

**GenEdQuestion.class**
The mode of quiz is multiple choice. I want to save or transfer the correct answer and the chosen answer to another activity (result). I transferred the score but i don't know how to transfer the result. How can I do that?

```
      answer1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (answer1.getText() == mAnswer){
                mNumber++;
                mScore++;
                number.setText(" "+mNumber+" .");
                if (mNumber == quizCount){
                    onFinish();
                }
                else{
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }
            }else{
                mNumber++;
                number.setText(" "+mNumber+" .");
                if (mNumber == quizCount){
                    onFinish();
                }
                else{
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    answer2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (answer2.getText() == mAnswer){
                mNumber++;
                number.setText(" "+mNumber+" .");
                mScore++;
                if (mNumber == quizCount){
                    onFinish();
                }
                else{
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }

            }else{
                mNumber++;
                number.setText(" "+mNumber+" .");
                if (mNumber == quizCount){
                    onFinish();
                }
                else{
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    answer3.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (answer3.getText() == mAnswer){
                mNumber++;
                number.setText(" "+mNumber+" .");
                mScore++;
                if (mNumber == quizCount){
                    onFinish();
                }
                else{
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }

            }else{
                mNumber++;
                number.setText(" "+mNumber+" .");
                if (mNumber == quizCount){
                    onFinish();
                }
                else{
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    answer4.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (answer4.getText() == mAnswer){
                mNumber++;
                number.setText(" "+mNumber+" .");
                mScore++;
                if (mNumber == quizCount){
                    onFinish();
                }
                else{
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }

            }else{
                mNumber++;
                number.setText(" "+mNumber+" .");
                if (mNumber == quizCount){
                    onFinish();
                }
                else{
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


   new CountDownTimer(60000*60, 1000){
        public void onTick(long secondsLeft){
            mCountDownGenEd.setText(""+String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(secondsLeft),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(secondsLeft) -
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(secondsLeft))));

        }
        public void onFinish(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GenEdQuestionsResult.class);
            intent.putExtra("this", mScore);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }.start();
}

private void onFinish() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GenEdQuestionsResult.class);
    intent.putExtra("this", mScore);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void updateQuestion(int i) {

    question.setText(mQuestions.getQuestion(i));
    answer1.setText(mQuestions.getChoice1(i));
    answer2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice2(i));
    answer3.setText(mQuestions.getChoice3(i));
    answer4.setText(mQuestions.getChoice4(i));
    mAnswer = mQuestions.getCorrectAnswer(i);
```

}

**GenEdQuestionsResult.class**
This activity will show the score and if the user passed or failed. How will i put the result here?

```
    mFinalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreTextView);
    mResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("this", 0);
    mFinalScore.setText(score+" / 20");
    if (score <= 10){mResult.setText("Failed");}
    else{mResult.setText("Passed");}
```

**This is the result i want to create**

[this is the picture of result i want to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY3Qk.png)

Comment: That's a lot of code. What exactly are you stuck on for passing the result? You just pass another extra through the intent and retrieve it as you do with the score.

Comment: @codeMagic i want to show the chosen answer and the correct answer in another activity. I tried the another extra but it showing null value

Comment: Ok, but you don't show how you try to send and receive it so we can't tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: I just added this few lines of codes  (**Main**) ----- private void onFinish() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GenEdQuestionsResult.class);
        intent.putExtra("this", mScore);
        intent.putExtra("answer", mAnswer);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
(**GenEdQuestionResult**)  ----  int score = getIntent().getIntExtra("this", 0);
        String answer = getIntent().getStringExtra("answer");
        mFinalScore.setText(score+" / 50");
        mAnswer.setText(answer); _It shows 'null' value in result activity_

Comment: That needs to be edited into your post. Reading lines of code and errors is a pain in comments. Use the edit button below the post. Also, tell us what is null and/or post the complete error message.

Answer (score 1):

you have 3 approaches to do this
the first one=> make a static variable and then you can access it where ever you want
,

the second one you can => use **intent putExtra**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondClass.class);
i.putExtra("answer", "myAnswer");
startActivity(i)
```

the third approach 
is using a sharedPreference take a look at this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preference like this:

```
public static final String answer = "answer"; //declare this globally at the top.
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(Commonclass.ANSWER,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
editor = prefs.edit();
String a = prefs.getString("answer","answer"); //to get the stored value
editor.putString(theme,"blue"); // to store your answer
editor.commit();
```

Create a Commonclass:

```
public class Commonclass 
{
  public static final String ANSWER = "answer" ;
}
```